# How use strongarm with domain access?

Tags: features, domain-access

Lets say I have 2 domains, A (Site A) and B (Site B). I achieved this with [domain access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module. Then with [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and [strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) I would like to export `site_name` variable from both domains. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the Domain Conf module which is a sub-module of [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) and provides you per-domain configuration.

> The Domain Access: Site Configuration module (called Domain Conf), is
>   an optional extension of the Domain Access module.  Domain Conf
>   provides options for configuring basic settings of your affiliate
>   sites to be different.